# Integrating coinbase commerce API in PHP

Tags: php, api, coinbase-api, coinbase-php

I am integrating Coinbase Commerce API in my PHP web application for accepting payments. I am taking reference from [official PHP library for the Coinbase commerce](https://commerce.coinbase.com/docs/)

So I have a `addfunds.php` Where can choose the amount and payments method, here is the code of add funds file
`

```
   $data = [
          
            "business_name" => "", 
            "customer_email" => $user['email'], 
            "customer_name" => $user['client_id'].','.$paymentCode.','.$method_id.','.$order_id, 
            "local_price" => [
                  "amount" => $amount, 
                  "currency" => "USD" 
               ], 
            "memo" => "Balance recharge - ".  $user['email'] 
         ];  
         $fields_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.commerce.coinbase.com/invoices');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'X-Cc-Api-Key: '.$extra['api_key'];
$headers[] = 'X-Cc-Version: 2018-03-22';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);

header('location:'.$result->data->hosted_url);
$success = 1;
$successText = "Your payment was initiated successfully, you are being redirected..";
```

`
This is how my code looks likes as of now, I am getting the details in $data json from my database, This code works. It redirects the user to the coinbase payment page.

`$result->data`

This return Json from Coinbase which contains all the details about transaction like amount, payment code, currency, invoice url... etc.

But I'm confused how I can authenticate the payment. Weather the payment is completed or not. I have checked The API documentation from coinbase. But I'm not getting it, I think I can do it with the conditional statement. So firstly I have to fetch the invoice of the user. For that I can get the. Payment food from `$result->data` and fetch the invoice. I can say this is how I can fetch invoice from coinbase

`

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.commerce.coinbase.com/invoices/invoice_code_or_invoice_id', [
  'headers' => [
    'accept' => 'application/json',
  ],
]);

echo $response->getBody();
```

`

I can use `$result->data->code in the place of invoice_code_or_invoice_id`   and get invoice status from it and check wheather the transaction is completed or not, by referring to [coinbase documentation about invoice status](https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/commerce/docs/payment-status)
but the problem is the payment period given is 60 minutes so i have to check this condition after 60 minutes? or how can i do it.
Thank you for reading my question i hope someone helps, thankyou

I tried myself to check the condition and do by i dont know about how can i check condition after specific time or how i know the statuss is marked complete